# How to get list of other executing scripts with their args using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

There are a number of scripts that run via wget from cron and other just from standard browser access. One or more of those scripts is crashing the MySQL database server. So far we haven't been able to figure out which by just looking at process logs because they don't show what args were included when the script was called.

Is there a way to get a snapshot of the process/request list along with args used on all scripts at that time when a database server crash is detected using PHP?

Running PHP 5.2.17, Apache 2.2.24, MySQL 5.1.70.

Comment: you could try [xdebug profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler)

Comment: `ps -auxwww`? of course, by the time you detect the crash and run ps, the bad process may have already exited anyways.

Comment: The easiest way would be just to log the arguments on access first & log 'clean' exits.